# Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence in SAP PI mapping

Tags: xml, utf-8, sap-erp, sap-pi, sap-xi

This is SAP PI scenario. The message is exchanged between 2 systems.  Source System: IPOS  Target system: ECC..  Once the message reaches PI system an xml corresponding to IPOS is generated. I have to map the IPOS structure to ECC structure.  Here I am using DOM parser..   I am using main() for testing purpose.

```
public static void main (String str[]) throws FileNotFoundException, StreamTransformationException { 

    ZcreateHomeDelivery obj = new ZcreateHomeDelivery();

    try { 


    InputStream inputStream  = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/XYZ/workspace/input.xml");

    FileOutputStream newOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/XYZ/workspace/output.xml");  
    obj.execute(inputStream, newOut);
    }catch (Exception e ) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

I have imported all the required packages..

```
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.AbstractTrace;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.StreamTransformation;
```

The problem I am facing is when I execute the code, I am getting error as

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipChar(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sap.nw.rr.hd.ZcreateHomeDelivery.execute(ZcreateHomeDelivery.java:85)
at com.sap.nw.rr.hd.ZcreateHomeDelivery.main(ZcreateHomeDelivery.java:801)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sap.nw.rr.hd.ZcreateHomeDelivery.execute(ZcreateHomeDelivery.java:101)
at com.sap.nw.rr.hd.ZcreateHomeDelivery.main(ZcreateHomeDelivery.java:801)
```

The solution that I have tried is

```
try
    {
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");// added
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(outdoc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(outputStream);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new StreamTransformationException("Mapping failed:Check input file", e);
    }
```

*added(Commented in the above code) to resolve the issue- But it dint help.  I have to add UTF-8 , But where to add it ?

This is resolved : solution is
1)Open the `xml` in notepad
2)Make sure you dont have extra space at the beginning and end of the document.
3)Select File -> Save As
4)select save as type -> All files
5)Enter file name as `filename.xml`
6)select Encoding - `UTF-8`-> Click Save

Comment: Can you show the content of the XML input you are parsing? Thanks.

Comment: @potame The XML file is very big.. Shall i upload any other  sample XML

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29434896/how-to-deal-with-java-encoding-problems-especially-xml) a reference to the problem. The problem is that the xml file declares a different encoding from the one used for saving the file.
If the files are encoded using iso-8859-1 and in the file it's declared as UTF-8 you can read the file using a reader and force the encoding to the correct one. the link shows the api for doing this.