# Build an artifact of javafx in intellij, encoding utf-8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, build

I made complete software and I can not manage to build its artifact, I searched the web for solutions and did not find any.

The problem that is written is:

```
Error:Java FX Packager: 
BUILD FAILED
Error reading project file C:\Users\עידן לוי\.IntelliJIdea2018.1\system\compile-server\אורתודנטיה_c902f87\_temp_\build.xml: Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence.
Total time: 0 seconds
```

In the software I also use Hebrew letters, and I also have a database in which some of the data is stored in Hebrew.

When I run the software it works and also when I build it in the jar.
The problem starts when I try to build it as javafx...

Thank you very much to anyone who can help

Comment: try to provide javm arguments for char encoding to JVM.

like `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 … com.x.Main`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the message "Invalid byte 2 of a 3-byte UTF-8 sequence" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320108/what-does-the-message-invalid-byte-2-of-a-3-byte-utf-8-sequence-mean)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320108/what-does-the-message-invalid-byte-2-of-a-3-byte-utf-8-sequence-mean

Comment: Perhaps this could help: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206155489-JavaFX-Packager-Error  (if I understand correctly, the proposed "solution" is to move the project to a directory with a purely-ASCII name).

Comment: non-ASCII is known to be problematic, especially with the native launchers provided with the JDK, some references here: https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/309#issuecomment-332288591

Comment: This is even not-yet-resolved with current JDK 10: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8138642
and passed arguments are not working too: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8133034

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much to everyone who helped.
I found the solution !!!
Because the idea folder is sitting in my user and it is written in Hebrew it made a problem ...
In guides I saw how to change the folder and it helped ...